# How i can use `WHERE` on `JOIN`?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql code

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.url, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",categories.color SEPARATOR ",") AS categories
        FROM sites
        LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id WHERE categories_data.deleted=0
        LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id WHERE categories.deleted=0
        WHERE sites.deleted=0 GROUP BY sites.id'
```

Where return this error

```
Database_Exception [ 1064 ]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id WHERE cate' at line 4 [ SELECT sites.id, sites.url, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",categories.color SEPARATOR ",") AS categories FROM sites LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id WHERE categories_data.deleted=0 LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id WHERE categories.deleted=0 WHERE sites.deleted=0 GROUP BY sites.id ]
```

So, how i can use `WHERE` on `JOIN`?

Thank.

Comment: You cannot use `where` on `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot add `WHERE` clause on the `ON` clause of the joint tables. Separate them with conditional operator (*AND/OR*),

```
SELECT sites.id, 
       sites.url, 
       Group_concat(categories.name, '|', categories.color SEPARATOR ',') AS 
       categories 
FROM   sites 
       LEFT JOIN categories_data 
              ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id 
                 AND categories_data.deleted = 0                  -- <<== HERE
       LEFT JOIN categories 
              ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id 
                 AND categories.deleted = 0                       -- <<== HERE
WHERE  sites.deleted = 0 
GROUP  BY sites.id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: it's normal. The difference between adding the condition on the `ON` clause rather than `WHERE` clause is, on the `ON` clause the filtering of records takes place before it will be joined on the other table, while on the `WHERE` clause the filtering takes place after the records from all tables defined has been joined.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND`

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.url, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",categories.color SEPARATOR ",") AS categories
        FROM sites
        LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id AND categories_data.deleted=0
        LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id AND categories.deleted=0
        WHERE sites.deleted=0 GROUP BY sites.id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was mentioned above, but alternatively you could specify all of these filters in the WHERE statements. This is what it might look like.

```
    SELECT sites.id, sites.url, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name,"|",categories.color SEPARATOR ",") AS categories

    FROM sites
     LEFT JOIN categories_data ON sites.id = categories_data.sites_id 
     LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_data.categories_id = categories.id

    WHERE 
     sites.deleted=0 
     and categories_data.deleted=0
     and categories.deleted=0

    GROUP BY sites.id'
```

When you've got errors, it might help to try the query in a very standard format before optimizing for speed and load.
SELECT...FROM...WHERE...GROUP BY etc.